# Big Android Wear Notifications

Tags: android, notifications, wear-os, android-wear-notification

I am looking into making a small Android Wear app. Everything is fine so far. However, screen usage is essential for my application. I am using a notification (setDisplayIntent) that hosts a custom activity. Compared to other apps, such as Google's own weather, the notification is only shown in the lower half of the screen. E.g., Google Now's amazon shipping notification covers more than 3/4 of the screen AND is expandable / scrollable on a tap.

I've set Notification.WearableExtender.SIZE_LARGE or even FULL_SCREEN but couldn't notice any size increasements.  Can anyone share the secret or point me to a open source project that does make such large notifications hosting activities?

It seems a BigTextStyle notification does just what I want. However, I need to have tiny pictures and a list inside the text. I tried with a Html.fromHtml and a custom image getter, but no success so far (see the little box with [obj]) https://dl.pushbulletusercontent.com/3LjSc6bGx533InsdvPz1dxMpFWUeJe97/screen.png

edit: i've looked up the sourcecode for android wear's BigTextStyle-notification but couldn't find out the trick behind the large size + expandability ( https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-wear-release/core/java/android/app/Notification.java )

it seems to be related to the hidden method Style::populateBigContentView